# Firebase: approach to storing room passwords

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm building a web application with Firebase and Angular5. I want to make possible to create/join private rooms (protected by password).

Currently I am at the stage of designing the database and can't really see how I can check user entering the correct room password without actually retrieving it from the firebase database (thus making it completely insecure).

Should I employ cloud functions for that matter. Or can it be done directly with firebase and I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in firebase.

Suppose part of your DB is laid out like :

`/chatRooms/$roomID/password = $PASSWORD`

Read/write permission to `/chatRooms/$roomID/password` is granted to the chatroom owner.

To become a member of a chatroom, you must add a document to:
`chatRooms/$roomId/users/$userId` with the following validation:

The entry's userId must be the current user, and the password field must equal the password. A verification rule can access ANY data in the database, even if the user cannot access the data.

Below is an (untested) example that will show the basic principles.

In short:

1. only the chatroom admin may set the password. No one may read it.
2. chat data can be read by a user if their uid is in the members collection
3. to add a member to the collection, they must write a password, equal to (at the time) the room password

code:

```
"chatrooms" : {      
  "$room_id" : {
    "chat data" : {
      ".read" : "root.child('/chattrooms/' + $room_id + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists()"
    }, 
    "password": {
      ".read": "false",
      ".write": "root.child('/chattrooms/' + $room_id).child('admin').val() == auth.uid"
    }, 
    "members" : {
      "$user_id" : {
        ".validate": "$user_id == auth.uid && newData.val() == root.child('/chattrooms/' + $room_id + '/password').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a reasonable solution. But could you explain a bit more on this:
"The entry's userId must be the current user, and the password field must equal the password. A verification rule can access ANY data in the database, even if the user cannot access the data."
Should I write a password when a user to?
chatRooms/$roomId/users/$userId
I'm new to firebase rules.

Comment: > and the password field must equal the password.
The password field must be equal to which password? How do we provide it without actually writing it to the database?

Comment: @DaniilAndreyevichBaunov The docs explain it here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/ If you read them you'l understand. The user must ATTEMPT to write themselves into the `/users` collection. If they succeed they must have known the password.

Comment: I’ve read the docs. Still don’t get how user must have known the password. How do we check it? What do we actually write to chatRooms/$roomId/users location? Just userId?

Comment: @DaniilAndreyevichBaunov it's updated. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, now it definitely makes sense. Thank you. That's actually the part I was asking whether users should also write password in your solution.

Comment: How would you go about pushing a new $room_id if there's no read/write rules on that node itself?

Comment: Depends on business rules for who's allowed to create a room. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this that doesn't require a server is by embedding the password into the path of the room. For example: if you have a room "general" and password "correcthorsebatterystaple", then you could model this as:

```
messages
    general_correcthorsebatterystaple
roomnames
    general
```

And secure it with:

```
{
  rules: {
    messages: {
      "$roomid": {
        ".read": true
      }
    "roomnames: {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules anyone can read the list of room names. But you can only read the messages of a room if you also know the password of the name.