# Firebase can't push data given the ruleset

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a password protected chat room and found this SO answer to user as an example:

[Firebase: approach to storing room passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761602/firebase-approach-to-storing-room-passwords)

The problem is, given the ruleset in the answer, I can't figure out how to push new data. My rules looks like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "myApp":{
            "chatRooms" : {
                "$roomID" :  {
                    "password": {
                        ".read": "false",
                        ".write": "root.child('myApp/chatRooms/' + $roomID + 'chatInfo').child('admin').val() == auth.uid"

                    },
                    "chatInfo" : {
                        ".read":true,
                        ".write": "data.child('admin').val() === auth.uid"
                    },
                    "members" : {
                        "$user_id" : {
                            ".validate": "$user_id == auth.uid && newData.val() == root.child('feeds/chatRooms/' + $roomID + '/password').val()"
                        }
                     },
                     "messages" : {
                         ".read" : "root.child('feeds/chatRooms/' + $roomID + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists()"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now I need to be able to push a new chatRoom. But if I call this:

```
var obj = {
    password: "test", 
    chatInfo : {admin: this.state.currentUser.uid, chatName: "foobar"}
};
firebase.database().ref(`myApp/chatRooms`).push(obj);
```

It fails because I don't have write rules to push to chatRooms/$uid. If I do this.

What is the correct way to push new data with rules like this?

Comment: Either move your rules 1 level up or make sure you write to the right location (this is possible using push() to generate a key)

Comment: @AndréKool but if I move my rules 1 level up I can't make use of the password technique shown in the linked thread correct?

Comment: Correct. Maybe better to use those rules in this question and show what exactly you are having problems with. I think I know what your problem is but I need a bit more (specific) info.

Comment: @AndréKool Ok I updated it to more like how I have it in the app, I thought it would just complicate the question. Basically I'm trying to push the chatRoom info into chatInfo (admin, name, date created, etc.) as well as set the password that will be used for others to join. I haven't really thought or cared about members or messages yet since I can't even get the chatRoom initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you have to write to the path(s) were your rules are.

To do that you will have to split up your `push()` into two parts: generating the key and actually writing the data:

```
// Generate the key (this happens client side)
var key = firebase.database().ref(`myApp/chatRooms`).push().key;

// Use the key to write your data

firebase.database().ref(`myApp/chatRooms`).child(key).child('chatInfo').set({admin: this.state.currentUser.uid, chatName: "foobar"});
firebase.database().ref(`myApp/chatRooms`).child(key).child('password').set("test");
```

Comment: This works! I didn't think you could push an empty object like that to get the key. I had to make a few small tweaks maybe do the ReactNative firebase I'm using. I had to get the key like this: `firebase.database().ref('myApp/chatRooms').push().key;` I also had to move the "password" set below the "chatInfo" set or else it wouldn't see the admin field.

Comment: @DasBeasto Are the corrections I made to my answer correct?